# Samba nautilus-share usershare is not visible from Windows

Tags: ubuntu, network-shares, samba

I am running Ubuntu, trying to share files with a windows computer. Sharing is working in other Linux machines when I access it via Gnome's built-in webdav sharing feature. However, I wanted to allow Windows computer to access that same folder.

I installed Samba as well as the `nautilus-share` package and used it to share my Public folder. I got a permissions error when I did this, and after some research was led to an answer which prompted me to run the following command: `sudo chmod a+rwx /var/lib/samba/usershares/`.

This removed the error and allowed the share to be created from within Nautilus. However, I was still unable to access the shared folder over smb. I am able to connect to the Samba server from the Windows machine, but the only share available is the $print share.

Further research had me add my user to the sambashare group. That did not resolve the issue. I also added the following to the (otherwise default) smb.conf:

```
usershare max shares = 100
usershare allow guests = yes
usershare path = /var/lib/samba/usershares
usershare owner only = yes
```

Still the share is not showing up. Running `net usershare list` on the server shows that the share should exist, and `net usershare info` yields the following:

```
[Public]
path=/home/xxxxxxxx/Public
comment=Stuff
usershare_acl=Everyone:F,
guest_ok=y
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error and this was the way to solve it:

#### Remove all samba related files and configuration files

```
sudo apt purge python3-samba samba-common samba-common-bin samba-dsdb-modules samba samba-vfs-modules smbclient
```

Optionally you can remove the packages and maintain the configuration files, but this could left wrong files in the middle. It's better to do a backup of your configuration files. Anyway, if you want to try it, use `remove` instead of `purge`.

#### Reboot

Not sure if it's completely necessary, but I did it this way.

#### Share files

Open Nautilus and share a file or directory. A warning is showed indicating the sharing service is not installed and allowing you to click to install it. Click, install and you're done!